# Storing arbitrary keys/values in iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, core-data

Is there a way to store arbitrary keys/values in iOS, I know I could create column that store JSON key-value in SQLite but I want something more efficient so I could be able to get only the values that I need from a queried record.

Preferably If I could do this without having external database (like LevelDB) but if you think this might be the only way, let me know which one you prefer.

**Update:**

The data will hold articles (long html articles, title and date, and other undefined data) retrieved from the server and other meta data, it will be retrieved and displayed every time the user opens the app. (thats why NSUserDefaults will not work for this use case)

Comment: Your update doesn't actually give any reason why `NSUserDefaults` would not work.

Comment: I mentioned that articles will be retrieved from a server. I don't think `NSUserDefaults` will be ideal to save long texts.

Comment: You can used with plist.

Comment: Not really enough information to offer an answer here. What format (JSON, XML etc) will the data be in? Will the html be contained within the payload or will it be a URL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've written an App that deals with 50MB texts(about 10,000 articles in HTML). They're indexed by an `articleID`. I've used LevelDB, raw Sqlite, Sqlite with FMDB, CoreData and NSUserDefaults in this App.

**Here's what I've learned:**

LevelDB gives you the arbitrary key/value access pattern and the reading speed is extremely fast if you're reading them sequentially. But if you need to read a key randomly (by not using it's iterator), it is much slower than Sqlite.

Raw Sqlite is fast for random reading if you use it correctly. (Use indexes, cover indexes, etc.)
But you will lose the ability to read and write arbitrary key/value.

FMDB gives you a nice Objective-C API but 50% CPU time is wasted when converting data between Objective C and C (NSString <-> char*) (It's still a lot faster than Core Data, 4X+)

Personally I think Core Data sucks. So I won't recommend it to anyone for any usage. Sorry I don't want to recall those pain when using CoreData.

NSUserDefaults is best for user setting and only for user setting, definitely not a solution for long articles.

**I use raw Sqlite and Google Protocol Buffer.**

Protocol Buffer is extremely fast for encoding and decoding. It also gives you the ability to add new fields by modifying it's .proto file, no DB scheme change is required. You can store several related keys in a single proto, let's say `articleMetaData.proto` contains the `title`, `author` and `publishDate`, if some time later you need to add `modifyDate` you just add it to the proto file and store the binary in Sqlite in the same column.

Answer (score 4):

A simple SQLite schema such as ID (indexed) | key | value should give you the freedom you want, with the speed and query capabilities you need. You can use a thin wrapper like FMDB to make it much easier to deal than the C SQLite API.

Comment: There will be a problem querying this data structure (unless saving all properties as strings). However, this could be modelled in CoreData using a `Property` entity which hold pointers to all possible value types (many columns sparely populated) and if a blob or long text is involved change the column to a relationship pointing to the actual value (encapsulated in the proper entity) as to not damage performance.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, rather than using NSUserDefaults which is fine for simple data, I would look into using the NSCoding protocol and NSKeyedArchiver. Have your objects implement the NSCoding protocol and then use something like this to archive/unarchive them:

```
+ (NSObject *)readArchiveFile:(NSString *)inFileName
{
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectoryPath, inFileName];

    NSObject *returnObject = nil;
    if( [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath] )
    {

        returnObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
    }

    return returnObject;

}

+ (void)archiveFile:(NSString *)inFileName inObject:(NSObject *)inObject
{
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectoryPath, inFileName];
    BOOL didSucceed = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:inObject toFile:filePath];
    if( !didSucceed )
    {
        NSLog(@"File %@ write operation %@", inFileName, didSucceed ? @"success" : @"error" );
    }

}

+ (void)deleteFile:(NSString *)inFileName
{
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectoryPath, inFileName];
    NSError *error;
    if ( [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath] && [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] != YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Also, I would look into using CoreData as it gives you the ability to query your data.

Answer (score 2):

Core Data sounds like what you need, not sure how many records you are planning on storing, if it's just one then maybe not Core Data but if it's lots then I would think Core Data would be ideal.

You may need to explain what you mean by storing arbitrary keys/values, based on your question it sounds more like structured data (title, date, text and other meta data fields), in which case Core Data would be perfect.

Comment: Core Data has another advantage: You can use NSFetchedResultsController, which is extremely useful if you want to display your data in UITableViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Look at NSUserDefaults.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have NSUserDefaults and there you can store information.

Have only a few things to retain:
1 - If you do not leave the app is necessary to do synchronize to store the information;
2 - You can store and get and edit you information always

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.emailToSend forKey:@"teste.email"];
[defaults synchronize];


NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].text = [defaults objectForKey:@"teste.email"];
```

Answer (score 0):

[YapDatabase](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase) can be another option if you just want to use sqlite

It provide API like this, which seems ideal for your use case.

```
- (void)setObject:(nullable id)object
           forKey:(NSString *)key
     inCollection:(nullable NSString *)collection
     withMetadata:(nullable id)metadata;
```